# res.send() is not showing any data

Tags: node.js, express

I have a simple express app:

```
const express = require('express');
const { json } = require('express/lib/response');
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3003
const path = require('path')


app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Called!")
    res.send('Welcome to Mini-Programs!')
})

app.get("/app", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./index.html"));
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

However, when I go to http://localhost:3003 I get nothing what mistakes am I making in this code?

Comment: What is shown in your terminal? What should `express/lib/response` be?

Comment: Your code works just fine for me when I run it and then go to `http://localhost:3003` in a browser.  I'd suggest making sure no prior server is still running on that port.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried, your code works fine!
However you can remove `const { json } = require('express/lib/response');` as you're not using it (you use `express` import to call `express.json()` which is fine).

Are you sure your server is starting on port 3003 ? You might be reading a different port from the `$PORT` environment variable, so it's not defaulted to 3003 as it is on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved and I did not change anything.

Comment: ahaha next time you might try to refresh your web browser before posting here !

Comment: next time make sure everything is correct

Comment: not too important as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Concellia

Ensure that you have node.js installed on your computer.
If you have not yet installed Express, you need to do so.
Use the node app.js command to run your app if your file name is app.js
Your code works fine.
A response is displayed at http://localhost:3003